# base64ArrayBuffer : why to use a mask to extract the first part of the chunk?

Tags: javascript, bitmask

On the below code, could we just write :

`a = chunk >> 18 // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18`

instead of :

`a = (chunk & 16515072) >> 18 // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18`

I don't see the benefit to use a mask, as we want to extract the first part from left of the chunk.

source :
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/garylgh/15b36876eb00b876a9c9)

```
function base64ArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
  var base64    = ''
  var encodings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

  var bytes         = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
  var byteLength    = bytes.byteLength
  var byteRemainder = byteLength % 3
  var mainLength    = byteLength - byteRemainder

  var a, b, c, d
  var chunk

  // Main loop deals with bytes in chunks of 3
  for (var i = 0; i < mainLength; i = i + 3) {
    // Combine the three bytes into a single integer
    chunk = (bytes[i] << 16) | (bytes[i + 1] << 8) | bytes[i + 2]

    // Use bitmasks to extract 6-bit segments from the triplet
    a = (chunk & 16515072) >> 18 // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18
    b = (chunk & 258048)   >> 12 // 258048   = (2^6 - 1) << 12
    c = (chunk & 4032)     >>  6 // 4032     = (2^6 - 1) << 6
    d = chunk & 63               // 63       = 2^6 - 1

    // Convert the raw binary segments to the appropriate ASCII encoding
    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + encodings[d]
  }

  // Deal with the remaining bytes and padding
  if (byteRemainder == 1) {
    chunk = bytes[mainLength]

    a = (chunk & 252) >> 2 // 252 = (2^6 - 1) << 2

    // Set the 4 least significant bits to zero
    b = (chunk & 3)   << 4 // 3   = 2^2 - 1

    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + '=='
  } else if (byteRemainder == 2) {
    chunk = (bytes[mainLength] << 8) | bytes[mainLength + 1]

    a = (chunk & 64512) >> 10 // 64512 = (2^6 - 1) << 10
    b = (chunk & 1008)  >>  4 // 1008  = (2^6 - 1) << 4

    // Set the 2 least significant bits to zero
    c = (chunk & 15)    <<  2 // 15    = 2^4 - 1

    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + '='
  }

  return base64
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be unnecessary. The left-most 8 bits are unused and always zero, the right-side bits get erased by `>> 18` anyways.

Comment: @ASDFGerte The left-most 6 bits can be different than 0. Nevertheless, I agree with the fact that the right-side bits get erased by >> 18, that's why I was asking. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: When talking about bitwise operations in javascript, i talk about 32bit values. The left-most 8bit (25th to 32th bit) should always be zero here.

Comment: @ASDFGerte In this function, a full chunk is 3 octets (24 bits) which is split in 4 parts of 6 bits. The 6 bits of the first part could be 1.
I may not understand what you say.

Comment: The bitmask is `00000000111111000000000000000000`. For it to be useless, both the zero groups need to be irrelevant. The right side is shifted away, the left side (left-most 8 bit) are always zero (base64 works on three-byte groups, 24bit total), so they are irrelevant too.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Indeed, you are right. I have just had a look on Google. It is something I didn't know. Thank you.